# Ubuntu 11.10 Faulty install, how do I rollback or troubleshoot?

Tags: linux, upgrade, ubuntu-11.10

So stupidly I allowed the upgrade of Oneiric before I thought better of it. I have gone through the installation and it has evidently bricked.

Errors observed:

- Eternally stuck at loading screen
- Network connection failed waiting 60 seconds
- initctl event failed
- modem_manager[1153] Could not get system bus

Could someone give me a hand figuring out exactly what is going on?

After F6'ing at startup this is what I get

[image: Failure to load screen]